# Woocommerce does not merge same product in the Checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am struggling with a problem within the checkout section.
I choose multiple quantity of a single product (product page) and it adds to the cart.
But when visiting cart it becomes 4 same but in individual lines.

It happened suddenly and I have deactivated all the new plugins.

[image]

Can you help me please?

Comment: I found the way, It didn't help only by disabling the plugins.
First, I disabled all the plugins, then I moved them to another folder, then I visited my plugins page and received plugins disabled error, and then I re-moved the plugins and activated them and the problem is solved